# Setting a picturebox image in another form

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I have set picturebox1 modifier to public and am using this code

```
ViewForm vf = new ViewForm();
vf.picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/mark.png");
```

The code has no errors but it is not setting the image

Comment: At first glance i'd say your path was not joining properly.  Try `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "mark.png")`

Comment: try redrawing the control:   vf.picturebox1.Invalidate()

Comment: Still not working, the picture stays as its original

Comment: is Mark.png in the root of the folder that the application is run from or is it in a different folder?  At this point there is not enough informatin for us to help and we are only guessing at what the issue may be.  if you put Application.StartupPath + "/mark.png" into a string, does it show the correct path, can you copy that path, from the watch screen, and put that in a run dialog and access the file?  need more info.....

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to display the form first, so the properties of the PictureBox can be set.

I test this in my computer and works fine:

```
  ViewForm vf = new ViewForm();
  vf.Show();
  vf.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Image.png"));
```